# Как поддерживать постоянную работу скрипта в фоновом режиме?

Tags: php, websocket, workerman

На сервере поднимаю websocket сервер [Workerman](https://github.com/walkor/Workerman). Данный сервер запускается через командную строку (php cli) командой `php start.php start`. Для того, чтоб сокет сервер работал в фоновом режиме использую `nohup` и запускаю таким образом  `nohup php Daemon.php start 2>&1 &`. Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что если вдруг в сокет сервере произойдет какой-то сбой, то он просто останавливается и соответственно пока еще раз в ручную его не запустишь, он работать не будет. Как можно сделать так, чтоб в случае каких-то сбоев сокет сервер сам перезапускался?

Пример вывода **nohup.out**, когда происходит остановка сервера:

```
------------------------------------------- WORKERMAN --------------------------------------------
Workerman version:4.0.10          PHP version:5.6.40-0+deb8u11
-------------------------------------------- WORKERS ---------------------------------------------
proto   user            worker          listen                      processes    status           
ssl     user            none            websocket://0.0.0.0:1234    1             [OK]            
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Press Ctrl+C to stop. Start success.
SSL handshake error: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:1407609C:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:http request 
Workerman[start.php] stopping ...
Workerman[start.php] stopping ...
Workerman[start.php] has been stopped
```

В данном случае произошла ошибка "рукопожатия" и все, сервер упал.

P.s. Понятное дело, что нужно избегать всяких ошибок, а не постоянно перезапускать его, но все же :)

Comment: Нужно запустить `php start.php start -d`. Так он сам запуститься в фоновом режиме.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для таких задач можно использовать `supervisor`.

`apt-get install supervisor`

В файле `/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf` (ubuntu, debian)
или в `/etc/supervisord.conf` для остальных, добавляем нового воркера

```
[program:php-socket]
command=php /path/to/my/server.php
stdout_logfile=/var/log/worker.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=www-data
numprocs=1
```

Если вам принципиально использовать `nohup` тогда поменяем `command` на
`command=nohup php /path/to/my/server.php`. Но как по мне в этом нет осой необходимости, так как супервизор сразу же подниме скрипт. Есть смысл если не ходите глобально увеличивать максимальное время работы скрипта [set_time_limit](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.set-time-limit.php)